# How to make Midnight Commander exit to its current directory on MAC

Tags: macos, mc

I am using Midnight Commander on MacOS (Sonoma 14.3) and I love it. The only problem that I have is that I am not able to exit to the current directory, despite trying to do what is said in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017391/how-to-make-midnight-commander-exit-to-its-current-directory). I have the alias in my `.bash_profile` in my home directory (`/Users/alrod`). If I type '`mc`' I start Midnight Commander (which means the alias is working), but it never exits to the current directory. Here is the line in my `.bash_profile`. I also tried to use the other script provided with no luck (the commented line).

```
alias mc=". /usr/local/opt/midnight-commander/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh"
# alias mc=". /usr/local/opt/midnight-commander/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.csh"
```

Does someone on MacOS have this feature working? Could you please share how you did it?

Comment: "*If I type '`mc`' I start Midnight Commander (which means the alias is working)*" Not necessary, it could be a binary from `$PATH`. Start debugging with `type -a mc`

Comment: @phd this is what I got:
`alrod@Albertos-MacBook-Pro ~ % type -a mc
mc is /usr/local/bin/mc`
Does this mean that I have always been calling the binary?

Comment: This is exactly what I said: `mc` is a binary, not an alias so post-`cd` doesn't work. You need to find out why it's not your alias. You've said you have `.bash_profile` — is it at `$HOME`? Are you sure your shell is `bash` and not `zsh`? `echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: I am a more experienced Windows user, I am on macOS because of my job not well versed on Mac matters, please excuse my ignorance. So I don't know where this command should go (`.bash_profile`, `zsh`). Positive that my `.bash_profile` in at `$HOME`, so maybe I should search for the `zsh` version? This is what I got for echo:
alrod@Albertos-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

Comment: `echo $SHELL` is a command-line command that displays an environment variable. w32 equivalent would be `echo %SHELL%`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, So should I create a .zsh in my `$HOME` directory and add the line that calls the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $SHELL` shows that your shell is `/bin/zsh` so it doesn't read `.bash_profile`. Copy your alias to `~/.zshrc` file; if the file doesn't exist create it — it's a simple text file the same way `~/.bash_profile` is (`~` means `$HOME` — your home/profile directory).

The simplest solution is

```bash
echo 'alias mc=". /usr/local/opt/midnight-commander/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

and then reread the file into all opened terminals with the command `. ~/.zshrc` or restart all your terminals/shells.

PS. See the list of initialization files for `zsh` in the docs at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: It works!!!, thank you. I have to move a lot of files around different workspaces so the fact that I was not able to navigate with mc was really, really frustrating. Now I can work harder, better, faster and stronger.

Comment: Yep. I love Midnight Commander, I've been using it since 1995. I remember domain mc.mx — [de Icaza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_de_Icaza) was living in Mexica when he created the first version. :-)))